# Proxy is empty after initializing successfully

Tags: php, ubuntu, dbus

I'm using the [PECL D-Bus extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/dbus) with PHP 5.5 on Ubuntu 14.04 to interract with [Clementine](https://www.clementine-player.org/).

As for now I'm able to connect to the session bus (exceptions are throwns when any error occurs), but when I initialize the proxy object I get an empty `DbusObject`, so I'm unable to call the D-Bus methods.

Here is the code I use (inspired from the [extension usage examples](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pecl/dbus/trunk/examples/)) :

```
$dbus = new Dbus(Dbus::BUS_SESSION);

$clementine_player_proxy = $dbus->createProxy('org.mpris.clementine', '/Player', 'org.freedesktop.MediaPlayer');

var_dump($clementine_player_proxy); // returns "object(DbusObject)#3 (0) {}"
```

Of course I checked with [d-feet](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Apps/DFeet?action=show&redirect=DFeet) if the bus name, the object path and the interface exists :

[image]

I'm stuck for two days.

Edit : [submitted bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67803) on the PHP bugreport.

Edit 2 : tested with another method (`Addtrack(string, bool)`) with another object path (`/TrackList`). It works. I don't understand.

Comment: have you tried invoking those methods? Long time ago i was var_dumping DOMDocument stuff and it didn't print much but the data and methods where there.

Comment: Yep, test script : http://pastebin.com/v3gqSwW8

Comment: You are right, tested with another method (Addtrack(string, bool)) and another object path (/TrackList), it works and the DbusObject is empty.

Comment: I had a look on the Pecl Dbus source and header files, as far as I understand it, it just relays any "method-call" directly to some C dBus lib. I suppose thats why var_dump is empty (because in fact in does not have any methods (except construct and 1 or 2 php-specific others))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up to learn Python to properly use D-Bus with ease via the [dbus module](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-python/doc/tutorial.html) (as said in the [Clementine's wiki](https://github.com/clementine-player/Clementine/wiki/Controlling-Clementine-from-the-commandline-with-DBus-and-MPRIS#using-python)).

I recommend to everyone who wants to use the PHP D-Bus extension to not do so : it is buggy, tricky and it has no documentation (except example scripts).